# table printing one more cell instead of new line

Tags: php, html

I am trying to limit the printing of table cells to 3 per row. This worked in one example, but clearly not working when I tried to use the same code somewhere else in the site. This is the code:

```
$n=3;
                echo "<table cellpadding='10' cellspacing='10' style='margin-right:-70px;'><tr>"; 
                $users_count = count($users);

                for($i=0; $i<$users_count;$i++)
                {
                    $temp = array();
                    $temp = $users[$i];
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo "<div id='kitchen_box'>";

                        echo "<div id='kitchen_box_details'>";
                            echo "<h4>".$temp->fullname . "</h4><br>";
                            if(strcmp($temp->address, '') == 0)
                                echo $temp->city;
                            else
                                echo $temp->address.", ".$temp->city;
                        echo "</div>";      
                            echo "<div id='kitchen_box_pic'><img id='kitchen_image' src='".$temp->profilepic."' /></div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                    echo "</td>";

                    if($i != 0){
                        if($i % $n == 0 && $i != $users_count-1){
                            echo "</tr><tr>";
                        }
                        else{
                            echo ""; //if it is the last in the loop - do not echo
                        }
                    }
                }
                echo "</table>";
```

I can't see why this wouldn't work! I would really appreciate support on the matter :)

Comment: *wouldn't work!* ? What exact problem you facing ?

Comment: table structure is strange. see : echo "</tr><tr>"; how does your table html look like after page is loaded?

Comment: @BojanKovacevic - I think it is fine. But still in else it should be `echo </tr>;`.to end last opened row. Still need more clarification though.

Comment: thats what u though by my comment. no closing tr. So table structure is almost surely NOT fine.

Comment: it is working and printing all 4 records in my database inside respective divs. The only problem it is printing all of them in one row...I need only 3 per row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. But your main issue is that you're using a zero-based increment, but doing a 1-based check. So, a table of your the results of an `$i!=0 && $i%$n==0` goes like this:

```
$i    $result
0    false
1    false
2    false
3    true
```

So, you see, the result closes the row after the fourth, not the third cell. To fix this, change the line to:

```
if($i % $n == $n-1 && $i != $users_count-1){
```

You should also include a closing `</tr>` tag with your closing `</table>` tag.

Incidentally, you shouldn't give the same ID to multiple elements on a page. Each of your `kitchen_box` and `kitchen_box_div` DIV tags will have the same ID. If you want this for CSS, use classes. Otherwise, you might try adding the value of $i to each ID.

*Nitpicking on request:*

The line `$temp = array();` seems a little pointless, especially since you don't want $temp to be an array, but an object.

The `else{ echo ""; }` lines are also redundant.

You don't need the `if($i != 0)` check now because that case will not pass the next test anymore.

Otherwise the code seems fine to me.

Comment: That worked! Thanks for the help. Would you mind pointing other problems/issues with code? So I can work on them :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your $i starts at zero.

Let's look at your conditions before creating a new row :

```
if($i != 0){
                    if($i % $n == 0 && $i != $users_count-1)
```

If $i = 0, the first condition isn't matched. Then the second isn't for $i = 1 and $i = 2. And then your script creates another ... in your first row before matching your if conditions for the first time.

I guess you could move this part of the code right after the beginning of the for instructions :

```
            for($i=0; $i<$users_count;$i++)
            {
                if($i != 0)
                {
                    if($i % $n == 0 && $i != $users_count-1){
                        echo "</tr><tr>";
                    }
                    else{
                        echo ""; //if it is the last in the loop - do not echo
                    }
                }

                // Echo your <td> ... </td>
            }
            echo "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: not very clear on what i should do. in for condition i changed 0 to 1 so it skipped first record